# How to ignore UI scaling in Pyglet window?

Tags: python, windows, pyglet

Sorry right off the bat, my English is bad. I use google translate.

Faced such a problem:

On my laptop, the interface scale is `125%`. The maximum resolution of the monitor is `1920x1080`, and I work with it.
While creating the Pyglet application window, with a resolution of `1280x720`, I noticed that the window is clearly larger than what I expected. Having changed the resolution to the maximum one available to me - `1920x1080`, using the second monitor, I realized that it is clearly larger than the main monitor.

For a long time and painfully, I figured out the cause of the problem, but found it out. When I set the interface scaling to `100%`, instead of `125%` that was comfortable for me, everything fell into place. The windows began to work as intended.

But this is not the way to solve the problem. Therefore, I have come to you with a question. How do I ignore the zoomed-in laptop interface in my application? Also, an alternative solution could be to change the scale of the interface while the application is running, and with this I would also like to contact you. Can someone suggest how to implement one of the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have guessed that the same problem could be with Pygame.
Solution:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/pygame-fullsreen-display-issue

Comment: This worked for my laptop's monitor as it is 125% scaled, however when trying to run fullscreen on a 2nd monitor that isn't scaled (or rather, set to 100%), applying this fix causes pyglet to wrongly detect the resolution of 2nd monitor as being larger than it actually is - as if trying to compensate for the same scaling % as my main screen. This just causes a crash complaining about it being an invalid resolution.